# CURL Post not working (Body is not being sent)

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

I have this method in which I am trying to send a `POST` request with `json` body:

```
public function executePost($url, $theBody, $headers){

    $data_string = '{"apple": "fruit", "turnip": "vegetable"}'; // hard coded for now                                                                               
    \Log::info($data_string);                                                                                               
    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_merge($headers, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    ));                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    \Log::info($result);
}
```

On the receiving end I do not get the data I do:

```
\Log::info(\Input::all());
```

and I get nothing i.e. an empty array. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this.

It works on another computer using WAMP, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 5.6.

Comment: would please show us the receiving end code ?

Comment: try to fetch data at the receiving end with $_POST = json_decode( file_get_contents("php://input"), true ); and print_r($_POST); it and var_dump($result);

Comment: tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: so $data_string that you are send first of all please check it, is this a valid json or not here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1):

Please try to pass like this

```
$data_string = '{"apple": "fruit", "turnip": "vegetable"}';                                                                                             
$ch = curl_init('http://requestb.in/13zghda1');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $data_string));                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                                                           
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Please check the response also on [https://requestb.in/13zghda1?inspect](http://Link%20to%20Response)
On backend you will get the data now

Comment: I need to send json input with the curl request.. and the curl post fields expects a string not a php array.

Comment: you need to use the header for json. First convert the array to json
`$data_string = json_encode($data);`
After that, you can set the settings for json
`

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);
`

Comment: I am doing that please see the entire method.

Comment: you need to use the php input method to read the content on your backend 
`
$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
$json = json_decode($jsonStr);
`
I used the test API Url & it seems to receive the raw data
https://requestb.in/13zghda1?inspect

Comment: tried that.. still getting empty.. The problem is at the sending side.. the receiver is working fine.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I figured it out, there is something up with the curl extension in my machine.. I tested the same code on a friend's machine and it worked ok.

Comment: Okay.. that was unexpected :) well if you like the answer for future questions . Please accept or upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the data look like this :

```
$post = [
   'username' => 'user1',
   'password' => 'passuser1',
   'gender'   => 1,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

if your want to post an array ($data), try this:

```
$data = ['apple' => 'fruit', 'turnip' => 'vegetable'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Comment: @MubasharAbbas why do you strictly need to send JSON and not create the JSON on the receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out after spending two days on it, that upon calling this method I was passing as the third argument (header), a token, which had a `\n` (mistakenly) at the end of it, and due to that character, the request body was being truncated.

I don't know why, but removing that `\n` fixed it.

So in future if someone runs into the situation, where your

> curl request body is not being sent or being truncated

then

take a look into your request headers for special chars that should not be there.